# Adding to cell value based on last non-empty cell in column in Google Sheets

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

In a column with periodic values (e.g., A1 = "1.1", A2 = " ", A3 = "1.2"), I can't find a solution to automate this.

That is, if A1 = "1.1", I want the next cell in that column to be a sequential number. In other words, if I paste whatever formula comes out of this post into A5, where A1 = 1.1 and A2 to A4 = blank, then A5 should = A1+0.1.

Answer (score 0):

Any easy solution non-VBA would be to run 2 separate columns alongside using this formula from B2:

```
=if(A2="",B1,B1+0.1)
```

If you then wanted to clean out some of the values from that list run another formula from C2 with:

```
=if(B2=B1,"",B2)
```

and then copy and paste this column as values.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding correctly, this formula could be entered in A5:

```
=MAX(A$1:A4)+0.1
```

and then that cell could be copied and pasted in other cells in that column, and the range reference should change as required.